# Disable banner in push notifications in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, onesignal

For Notification Service im using OneSignal SDK. Is it possible to change notification settings from code?
I would like to allow only notification center, badges, sound.

But when i try to set it by

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        
       UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.sound, .badge]) { (success, error) in
            print(self,#function,success)
        }
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        
        return true
    }
        
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        completionHandler([.sound,.badge])
    }

}
```

The notification came up and showing with Banners and on Lock screen.

I set it manually and it works really cool.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQwmM.png

Will be great to set it up from code.

Comment: No, you can ask for specific notification type permissions initially, but from that point on the user controls the notification settings.